# How To Insert Data Within Two Tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to insert data using multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391851/how-to-insert-data-using-multiple-tables)

What i Have Done is Create two Tables

1. Table1 - RollNo,Fname,Mname,Lname
2. Table2 - Rollno,Marks

Now I have Set the Foreign Key as RollNo

Now the Point is :-

I have used the DetailsView in ASP.NET in Default mode as Insert

In the Data Source Config I Have Written the query for SELECT as the INNER JOIN of the Two Tables
This is Perfect.

The PROBLEM IS WITH THE INSERT QUERY.It does not allow me to Insert values into Two Tables

From the Above it is Clear that for my INSERT operation Fname,Mname,Lname is from Table1 and Marks is Table2.And Rollno is foreign Key.So How do I do This

INSERT INTO TWO TABLES.FROM a Single User Form

Keep In Mind Guys I Am using DetailsView in Asp.NET which allows me select only one SQLDataSource at a time..

Comment: Thi is not exactly a duplicate. This question seems to be (more) about using the ASP.NET DataSource component. Prets, Edit your question to focus it better. And do add some formatting.

Comment: @Henk - the actual question only references `ASP.NET` once, and he specifically says `THE PROBLEM IS WITH THE INSERT QUERY`.

Answer (score 1):

Inserts are by design single table operations.  If you want to insert into two related tables you need to insert into the primary table first, retrieve the key just created and insert into the second table with the key you just retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure and Transactions to perform your two insert statements.  But you cannot perform an insert on two tables at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You cant insert in both tables at once first you have to insert the primary key stuff than come to the foreign key table..You can use @@IDENTITY which will give you the primary key value against your insertion then you can use it to insert in second table

Use This way

```
  Insert into Table1(FName, MName, LName)
  values(@val1 , @val2, @val3)

  Insert into Table2(RollNo, Marks)
   values(@@Identity, val4)
```

Comment: Use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY - on a busy server you can not guarantee that @@IDENTITY will be the one you want.

Comment: Doesnot Allow me to Edit it Code...Shows Only One InsertCommand Tag Can Be Used in the Table

Comment: thanx @Greebo to increase my knowledge...